# Soap UI Groovy MQQueueConnection Issues, timeout when no message is found in Queue

Tags: jms, soapui

We have a requirement in Soap UI, where we have to read a message from a JMS Queue, i have managed to make the connection into JMS Queue via MQQueueConnection and read the message but below are the issues i faced which i couldnt resolve:

1) It is always reading the first message in the Queue, which is techincally the oldest message, ideally it should read the latest message i.e. last(which we can achieve via JMS Listner(Spring Boot) not sure how we can apply the same in Soap UI, we have to use Soap UI due to other limitations and dependencies)???

2) Is there any TimeOut which can be applied, in case of if there is no message in the queue, as of now it is going in an infinite search and hangs the Soap UI???

My Groovy:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.jms.JMSConnectionHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.jms.util.HermesUtils
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.jms.JMSEndpoint
import hermes.Hermes
import javax.jms.*

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;

import com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage;
import com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSender;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession;

context.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue("receivedMessage","")

  try {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();

    // Config
    cf.setHostName("agdevesb01");
    cf.setPort(14141);
    cf.setTransportType(1);
    cf.setQueueManager("AGDEV1T1");
    cf.setChannel("CLIENTS.CARRIER");

    MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
    MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    //MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///Q1");
    MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///QUEUE_NAME")
    MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);
    MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue);

//    long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
//    JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage("SimplePTP "+ uniqueNumber);

    // Start the connection
    connection.start();

//    sender.send(message);
//    System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

    JMSMessage receivedMessage = (JMSMessage) receiver.receive(1000000);

    //System.out.println("\\nReceived message:\\n" + receivedMessage);
    log.info "Received message: " + receivedMessage
    context.testCase.testSteps["Properties"].setPropertyValue("receivedMessage",receivedMessage.toString())


    sender.close();
    receiver.close();
    session.close();
    connection.close();

    //System.out.println("\\nSUCCESS\\n");
    log.info "SUCCESS"
  }
  catch (JMSException jmsex) {
    //System.out.println(jmsex);
    log.info jmsex
    //System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
//    System.out.println(ex);
//    System.out.println("\\nFAILURE\\n");
log.info ex
  }
```

Comment: why do you do a receive() for 1000 seconds (= 1000000 milliseconds) ? That call would block - so maybe you should change that to be just 5 seconds or so with receiver.receive(5000)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wait in the get initiation options:

```
    import com.ibm.mq.MQGetMessageOptions
    import com.ibm.mq.MQC

    MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions()
    gmo.options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT
    gmo.waitInterval = 1800000
```